# Weblogic creating EAR folder in WL_User temp folder

Tags: eclipse, caching, jvm, ear, weblogic11g

Trying to restart from command line weblogic server but it is picking up EAR file i deployed from Eclipse previously. Thought it was some kinda caching issue so opened/closed eclipse and cmd no help. Still picking up this EAR even when i delete it manually from the temp folder WL_User. Cant start weblogic from Eclipse as weblogic closes suddenly due to VM shutdown request and eclipse hangs on publishing state. Not sure why it does that too no error messages except BEA: VM requested Shutdown.

Very confusing how it is picking it up. Really want to understand why? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your weblogic domain is in a bad state. Normally I would suggest removing a deployment by opening the weblogic admin console and navigating to `Deployments` and then deleting the problematic deployment. If you can't do that, try the following:

Navigate to `<domain folder>/servers/<server causing problems>`

- Delete the `tmp`, `data`, `cache`, and `logs` folders

Restart your server.

Another option (you should only use if you are really stuck) is to edit the following file:

- `<domain folder>`/config/config.xml
- search for and remove your `<app-deployment>`

If it still doesn't work, you have other problems with your VM. Edit the question and add more info as necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did try deleting the folders in Admin Server. But looks like it is picking it up from the config.xml. I can see it is pointing to eclipse metadata folder. <app-deployment>
    <name>Ear</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>C:\Users\myworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\Ear\beadep\my_domain\Ear</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
  </app-deployment>

Comment: What should i change it to? or should i just delete the source path?

Comment: Wow just removing the source path line solved it. Man, worked on eclipse for long time, still learning new things. Thanks for the help